# Где ошибка! Помогите

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = int(input())
last_digit = x % 10
answer = 'NO'
while x > 0:
    last_digit1 = x % 10
    if last_digit == last_digit1:
        answer = 'YES'
    x = x // 10
print(answer)
```

Данный код должен сравнивать каждое число в значении, если они все одинаковы выведет YES, если нет NO. Но у меня на значение с разными числами все равно возвращает YES. Я уже визуализировал этот код, но не могу понять в чем причина. Помогите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проверка написана так, что ответ будет `YES`, если хотя бы один раз совпало `last_digit == last_digit1`. Очевидно, это не то, что вам нужно, т.к. ответ `YES` должен быть только в том случае, если совпадение повторяется на каждом шаге цикла.

Я бы предложил делать наоборот - проверять, что хотя бы в одной из проверенных пар цифры НЕ совпали.

Ну и ещё замечание по поводу именования. У вас переменные называются `last_digit` и `last_digit1`. В то время, как только одна из них всегда содержит именно последнюю цифру. А вот вторая содержит по очереди все цифры числа. Приучайтесь с самого начала обучения давать переменным имена, которые ясно отражают их смысл. Такая привычка здорово облегчит вам жизнь в будущем.

```
x = int(input())
last_digit = x % 10
answer = 'YES'
while x > 0:
    cur_digit = x % 10
    if cur_digit != last_digit:
        answer = 'NO'
    x = x // 10
print(answer)
```

Ну и ещё можно делать выход из цикла уже после первого несовпадения. На ответ это не повлияет, но улучшит быстродействие кода.

Comment: Спасибо, вот это помощь, а не то что выше

Comment: @АлексейКарнеенко очень мило с вашей стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Вы сравниваете `last_digit` с `last_digit1`. Если они равны получаете `YES`.
last_digit у вас равен `x % 10`,
И last_digit1 у вас равен `x % 10`.
И каким образом они могут хоть когда-нибудь не совпасть?

Comment: Все равно не понял, можно подробнее ?